# Better way to create class dict entries from a loop than locals()

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've been told it's bad form to use locals() to dynamically create variables in Python. However, I'm writing a class (using Django and Wagtail), and I really do need these things to go in the class dict, a.k.a. the `class` statement's local variables, not in a separate data structure:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    for language in languages:
        locals()['body_' + language] = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

I don't think I can set these after the class statement with `setattr`, either, because Django's metaclass processing will already have happened by then.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use a dictionary perhaps.

Comment: ...okay, for a class statement, particularly if the metaclass does any important work (which seems fairly likely here), `locals()` may actually be justified (and will probably actually work, unlike modifying `locals()` in a function).

Comment: The better way **is to not do this at all and to use some sort of container**.

Comment: What's RichTextField? It sounds Django-related, but there seem to be multiple libraries providing a RichTextField for Django. Also, what's Page?

Comment: RichTextField is a field type for Wagtail, a Django-based CMS . Page is the particular Blog entry. So there will be multiple `Page`s of class BlogPage. I will not need to modify these Rich Text Fields, and actually, later on there is a process `content_panels = Page.content_panels + [  FieldPanel('body_en'),` where 'body_en' needs to match the RichTextField declaration above, so if it's inside a dict, I'm not sure how that works

Comment: I've made a few edits to try to distinguish this question from ordinary dynamic-variable-names questions. If I got something wrong, you can edit again, or roll back my changes if they're completely off.

Comment: @user2357112 - yes, I'd say this is accurate

Answer (score 1):

The problem with having the different languages be attributes of the model is that changing the languages requires migrating the database. This is not something you ever want to do if you can help it.

The correct way to solve this is to use a separate model that maps a page and a language to the appropriate contents.

```
class BlogPageTranslation(model.Model):
  language = TextField()
  blogpage = ForeignKey(BlogPage)
  content = RichTextField()
```

Then when querying the page look for translations with the desired language and a sane default, and then take the appropriate row.

```
xlatcontents = BlogPageTranslation.filter(blogpage=Page,
  language__in=[someLanguage, 'en'])
somethingsomething(xlatcontents, someLanguage)
```